# removing • character in string

Tags: vb.net

i tried to read html contents by striping html tags in a string.
when i try to print that string i got • character. can anyone tell me how to remove this character

Comment: Please post some code and some stripped html for us to see how it looks.

Comment: Like ukhardy says, post a code sample. The dot looks like it might be a stock replacement for a non-ascii char but unless we can see how you got that string in the first place its hard to help.

Comment: @ukhardy,Vman:i replaced the dot like this..it is working          str2 = str2.Replace("&#149;", "")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
stringVal = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringVal)); //Swaps out non-ascii to '?'s.
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Replace()` function of String

```
 str = "Hello• World"
 str = str.Replace("•", "")  'Hello World
```

Comment: @Neha Raje, I think there are different chars but looking same. Check ASCII of these chars.

Comment: @Neha, `i = Asc("•")`  where `i` is an Integer

Comment: @javed, but even if i get its ascii value how will i remove it further

Comment: i wrote this code..it shows me value of str="" bot still prints the dot...:(                                                           Dim ascii As Integer = Asc("•")
str2 = str2.Replace(Chr(ascii), "")

Comment: @javed, it is working now...its ascii value was 149 but replaced it like this ... str2 = str2.Replace("&#149;", "")..